# Чтение данных из файла и заполнение массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

Только начал изучение питона и столкнулся с задачей на которую не могу найти решения.
Имеется .txt файл в котором 2 строчки целочисленных данных

Первая строка - общее количество последующих данных

Вторая - Сами данные через пробел

Т.е. примерно такое:

4

4 82 30 29

Задача - заполнить массив числами из второй строки.

Можете дать хотя бы наводки на то, что надо загуглить и изучить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я конечно тоже не асс в python, но не очень понимаю зачем здесь вообще первая строка нужна...
вот если бы вводные имели формат типа:

```
4
4
82
30
29
```

Тогда в этом был-бы хоть какой-то смысл. А так:

```
file = open('input.txt').readlines()
arr = [int(i) for i in file[1].split()]
```

Или так:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    arr = [int(i) for i in file.read().splitlines()[1].split()]
    file.close()
```

А гуглить нужно самые азы. Могу порекомендовать pythontutor.ru как отправную точку

Comment: Наверное, что бы ввести в заблуждение. Не я задачу составлял для себя

Comment: я бы добавил перед генератором или в самом генераторы условие len(file)>0, иначе возможно исключение если в файле не будет необходимого количества строк.

Comment: По хорошему, если забить на тип данных которые добавляются в список, то генератор там вообще нафиг не нужен, а на счет условия, то если бы речь шла о приложении с которым работает пользователь, то да... без "защиты от дурака" никак, но здесь, судя по всему речь идет об учебном задании, в которых, как правило, все вводные (хотя-бы) формально соответствуют условию, посему думаю, что этим можно принебречь